# android-youtube-api makes error when playing youtube contents with ad

Tags: android-youtube-api

android-youtube-api makes error when playing youtube contents with ad.

```
Version of youtube apk is latest : 11.04.56
AndroidVer: KitKat(4.4.4)
Status: contents with advertisement, click play button in YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.
```

this is error log below...

```
02-29 13:04:41.573 27114-27114/? E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: MEDIA_AD_PLAY_REQUESTED VideoStageEvent received by AdStatsClientManager without an AdReporter being constructed.
02-29 13:04:42.168 27114-27114/? E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Trying to do interaction logging without setting an InteractionLogger
02-29 13:04:42.183 29397-29397/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'tc', referenced from method sz.<clinit>
02-29 13:04:42.188 29397-29397/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'tb', referenced from method sz.<clinit>
02-29 13:04:42.188 29397-29397/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'td', referenced from method sz.<clinit>
02-29 13:04:42.188 29397-29397/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'ta', referenced from method sz.<clinit>
02-29 13:04:42.198 29397-29397/? A/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread[main,5,main]
02-29 13:04:42.208 29397-29397/? A/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.sec.android.app.aaaaa, PID: 29397, Version: 4.1.01-5
                                                   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: tc
                                                       at sz.<clinit>(SourceFile:145)
                                                       at ipw.e(SourceFile:250)
                                                       at bom.run(SourceFile:74)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5752)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-29 13:04:42.218 29397-29397/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.sec.android.app.aaaaa, PID: 29397
                                                   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: tc
                                                       at sz.<clinit>(SourceFile:145)
                                                       at ipw.e(SourceFile:250)
                                                       at bom.run(SourceFile:74)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5752)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: worth also following here https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8044&q=label%3AAPi-YouTube%20java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError%3A%20us&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary